# VBA User Function Checking a Directory

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code so far

- I often times have to check if a Purchase Order has been saved in a directory, there could be hundreds of purchase orders listed in Excel.
- As the Workbook changes, so often does the filepath.
- As such, I would like to make a function that asks for a cell value that contains a string for the filepath, and then a a cell for the PO #.

I'm a little stumped on how best to past information from the Excel sheet.  I need a cell reference for the filepath to the directory, and a cell reference for the PO #.
I've been able to make this work with a subroutine, that is what is posted below.  This is the third VBA Program I've worked on, please let me know if there is more legwork I should do before posting this:

```
Dim directory As String
Dim TempfileName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

Sub Check_PO()

x = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = 2 To 673
While Cells(x, 14) = 0
x = x + 1
Wend

i = Cells(x, 14)
TempfileName = "\\network\file\name\here\" & "*" & i & "*.pdf"
directory = Dir(TempfileName, vbNormal)

    While directory <> ""
        Cells(x, 18) = "Matched"
        directory = Dir
    Wend

Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple UDF:

```
Public Function HaveReport(fPath As String, fileName As String)
    HaveReport = IIf(Dir(fPath & fileName, vbNormal) <> "", _
                     "Matched", "Not Matched")
End Function
```

Usage:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you.

I've adapted it slightly to suit my needs:
    Public Function HaveReport(fPath As String, fileName As String)
        HaveReport = IIf(Dir(fPath & "*" & fileName & "*.pdf", vbNormal) <> "", _
                         "Matched", "Not Matched")
    End Function

I am having trouble calling the function however - the message box suggests that is is a name issue - but I am following your example exactly.  I'm thinking either its the excel version or maybe I'm not loading the function into the right worksheet? Thoughts?

Comment: The function should go into a regular code module (not a worksheet module or ThisWorkbook)